# Проверка на заполнение поля EditText

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Реализовал следующее: Есть несколько компонентов EditText, если одно или все поля пустые - вызываю метод1, если поля заполнены вызываю метод2.

И все бы хорошо, но после того как поля заполняю - и нажимаю кнопку, пишет что поля не заполнены. Возможно я что-то упустил.

Мой код:

```
int etN, etF, etP, etE;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.regictration);

        nameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    familReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.famil);
    elMailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elMail);
    passWordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

    Button btnRegOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);

    btnRegOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            nameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            familReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.famil);
            elMailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elMail);
            passWordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
            if (nameReg.getText().length() == 0)etN = 0;
            if (familReg.getText().length() == 0)etF = 0;
            if (elMailReg.getText().length() == 0)etE = 0;
            if (elMailReg.getText().length() == 0)etP = 0;
            if ((etN == 0) || (etF == 0) || (etE == 0) || (etP == 0)) {
            //Поля не заполнены 
   methodOne();
            }else{
    methodTWO();
            ///Все полязаполнены
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком,  он быстро помогает найти такие глупые ошибки и экономит много времени

Comment: Не надо получать ссылки на виджеты несколько раз, это ресурсоемкая операция и просто бессмысленно, потому что они не меняются. Это делается один раз в onCreate() и хранится в полях класса. Для двух состояний (да\нет, содержит\не содержит, полный\пустой и тд.) есть булевые переменные (boolean) принимающие значение false\true. Использовать для такой логики целочисленный тип избыточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы скопипастили неверно свой код

```
 if (elMailReg.getText().length() == 0)etE = 0;
 if (elMailReg.getText().length() == 0)etP = 0;
```

В последней строке должно быть **passWordReg** и, т.к. по умолчанию переменные типа **int** инициализируются 0 вы и получаете то, что получаете.